# Express $a^5$ in terms of $c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2.$

Tags: field-theory, proof-verification

Let $F=\mathbb Z_2,f(x)=x^3+x+1\in F[x].$ Suppose $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension of $F.$ Then $F(a)\simeq F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ and there is an isomorphism $$\phi:F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\to F(a):g(x)+\langle f(x)\rangle\mapsto g(a)$$ and $F(a)=\{c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2:c_i\in F\}.$ *I would like to express $a^5$ in terms of $c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2.$*

My Attempt: I've first consider the element corresponding to $a^5$ in $F[x]/\langle f(x)$ viz $x^5+\langle f(x)\rangle.$ Now $x^5+\langle f(x)\rangle\\=x^2(x^3+x+1)-(x^3+x^2)+\langle f(x)\rangle\\=-(x^3+x^2)+\langle f(x)\rangle\\=-(x^3+x+1)+x-x^2+1+\langle f(x)\rangle\\=x-x^2+1+\langle f(x)\rangle$

So the element corresponding to $x-x^2+1+\langle f(x)\rangle$ is $a-a^2+1.$ But the answer is $a^2+a+1.$

**I don't understand where did I go wrong!**

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2 {}$

Comment: Well, in characteristic two, plus is minus.

Comment: Why does $a^2\in\mathbb Z_2.$ $a$ is in a extension of $\mathbb Z_2!$

Comment: $a^2\notin\mathbb Z/(2)$, but the characteristic is a property shared by all the fields that contain $\mathbb Z/(2)$. After all, since $-1=1$ in $\mathbb Z/(2)$, it then follows that $-z=z$ in any old ring containing $\mathbb Z/(2)$.

Comment: Since their unity is common. Right?

Comment: Very roughly speaking, any identity that occurs in the base field carries over to its extensions. But that statement is much too rough to hang your hat on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2 {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It’s evident that OP didn’t yet understand that the characteristic is inherited by the extension rings.